Airshow pilots not making radio calls - best course of action
I recently flew into an air show, where some very large, fast and expensive historical aircraft were being flown. It is important to note that although this was within an ATZ, it was uncontrolled airspace, with a ground-radio facility and no service available.
The approach was fine as they weren't in the circuit when I arrived. However, on departure it was very busy, the air show aircraft were in the circuit taking people up and landing from experience flights.
I taxied to the "holding point" of the runway in use and received the usual "take-off at your own discretion" from the ground operator. To my surprise, one of the historical aircraft was on final and landed. They hadn't made any radio calls including downwind or final.
Of course, I now didn't know if there was another one behind it, so I made a radio call:
"[callsign], holding short of runway xx, ready for departure, but one of the xxx aircraft has just landed without making any radio calls, do we know if anyone else is in the pattern?"
The aircraft in question immediately responded:
"We're always listening in on frequency, you're good to go".
I found this statement odd, what's the use in listening if you're not speaking, I thought.
Anyway, I had a good look around, took off and left without incident, as I departed the airspace, I heard much more radio activity, including pattern calls from the various historical aircraft, I don't know if this was related to my previous announcement.
So onto the question, what is the best course of action at such events, when radio calls are not being made? I am concerned that I've missed something and perhaps these type of aircraft are not expected, or it is not common practice, for them to make GA calls and maybe I sounded like a douche :) I would like to know the etiquette for future fly-ins.

Always file a safety report if you feel safety was violated.

Flying in to an airshow, or a fly-in (or anywhere with a high volume of traffic for that matter) is a complex and dynamic environment. You absolutely need to be on your listening and watching game!
Remember "Take off at your discretion" is not a clearance. What it essentially means is that you have reached the limit of what ATC can clear you for, and you're now responsible to see and avoid.
The fact is, the pleasure flight/display crews should absolutely have been making calls and if they were not, then it is them that was in the wrong not you.
If at any time you think this impacted the safety of your flight I strongly suggest you file a MOR form - which includes "Voluntary Occurance Reporting":

Other safety related information which is perceived by the reporter as an actual or potential hazard to aviation safety


On another note, are you 100% sure that you did not miss a downwind/base/final call by that aircraft? It's easy enough to do and I can tell you we've all done it!


"We're always listening in on frequency, you're good to go"

This tells me that this pilot was well aware that you were ready for departure, and may well have executed a go around had you have taxied out to the runway. Is this the right thing to do? Possibly not, but you have to expect the pilot of a warbird/commercial pleasure flight would have been far more qualified and experienced than you or I. They, for the most part, REALLY know what they're doing.

I don't think it sounds like you did anything wrong here per se. It's all a good learning experience and it sounds like you learnt some new skills that day. Mission accomplished!

Your best course of action is to make your radio calls and talk to the "air boss" (a North American expression describing the person who is supposed to coordinate airplanes at a fly-in or show) per the normal protocols, but realize this is not a professionally "controlled" environment (ATC wise) and assume, for your own survival, nobody knows what they're doing and you're on your own in the chaos.
That means, go through the steps, follow the protocols for comms etc., but assume other aren't and don't take any action until you confirm visually that it's safe. This means you back track after broadcasting your actions and visually confirming nobody is on final, sit at the button facing the approach path while you get ready, then broadcast your actions and turn around and take off when you are sure nobody's coming, and assume airplanes could be randomly crossing your path and have your head outside the cockpit as you leave.
It's still on you to make sure you don't run into anybody or they don't run into you, to the extent you reasonably can. I fly out of an airfield with a lot of glider activity, and this is a basic fact of life; people are making calls in the circuit, but you have to assume someone could be out there that isn't, so don't take anything for granted.
